# Begin search when input parameter length =8

Tags: php, javascript, html

I use two files to search.  `index.html` makes a form to call a PHP search function (`ss.php`)

index.html code:

```
<form action="ss.php" method="get">
     <input name="q" type="text"> 
     <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

and ss.php code (php search function):

```
<?php
  $dir = 'ups';
  $exclude = array('.','..','.htaccess');
  $q = (isset($_GET['q']))? strtolower($_GET['q']) : '';
  $res = opendir($dir);
  while(false!== ($file = readdir($res))) {
    if(strpos(strtolower($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) {
      echo "<a href='$dir/$file' target = '_blank'>$file</a>";
      echo "<br>";
    }
  }
closedir($res);
?>
```

I want searches to begin when the input parameter's length is eight digits.

EDIT:

thanks to every body
solved
i used this code:

```
<form action="ss.php" method="get"><input name="q"
type="text" pattern=".{8,10}" title="8 to 10 characters" maxlength="10">
<input type="submit"></form>
```

Comment: You can do this by javascript. or you can add condition in your php code.

Comment: You have to use javascript. HTML and PHP alone cannot do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(textbox).keypress(function() {
    if(this.length >7 {   
       //ajax call
    }
});
```

This is the format you need

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible would be to attach a submit event when users have typed 8 characters.

Try this onkeyup="..." event:

```
<input name="q" type="text" onkeyup="if (this.value.length >= 8) { document.forms[0].submit() }">
```

Edit:

The above doesn't allow more than 8 characters. If you're using jquery, try this:

```
onkeyup="if (this.value.length >= 8) { $.post('/form-action', { q: this.value }, function(response){ alert(response); }); }"
```

Comment: He probably doesn't want that, as that would mean you can't type more than 8 characters.

Comment: True - have edited to include AJAX version - I did say the simplest possible solution though!

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<form id='form' action="ss.php" method="get">
    <input id='input' name="q" type="text"/> 
     <input type="submit"/> 
</form>
```

javascript:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.onkeypress = function(){
    if(input.value.length >= 8){
        form.submit();
    }

}
```